# Store remote sensing metadata created from STAC into PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, stac

I have created some STAC catalogs for remote sensing data (Landsat, etc.) that I would like to store in PostgreSQL/PostGIS for easier access and management.

How would I import the STAC created metadata into PostgreSQL/PostGIS?